# Incompatible types with new class?

Tags: java, android

In this example, where I have interface
and I have class , when I write this code

```
MediaPlayer P = new MP3;
```

The problem happens. 
Knowing that I applied the same line to another example 
and there is no problem. 
I need to fix the problem and understand why it's necessary

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MediaPackage player = new MP4();
        MediaPlayer P = new MP3();

    }

}


/// 
public interface MediaPackage {
    void playFile(String filename);
}

/// 

public interface MediaPlayer {
    void play(String filename);
}

// 

public class MP3 implements MediaPlayer {


  @Override
  public void play(String filename){
    System.out.println("Playing MP3 File " + filename);
  }



}

// 

public class MP4 implements MediaPackage{

@Override
public void playFile(String filename){
    System.out.println("Playing MP4 File " + filename);
   }
}
```

Comment: what is this code `public interface MediaPackage` ?  Does not look like java

Comment: Interface MediaPackage is separate from Class MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following piece of code, you're using (without knowing it) as reference *Android Media Player* (`android.media.MediaPlayer`) instead of your `MediaPlayer` interface (`com.ahmedco.adapter.example2.MediaPlayer`).

```
MediaPlayer P = new MP3();
```

So, maybe change it to:

```
com.ahmedco.adapter.example2.MediaPlayer P = new MP3();
```

Or simply change the name of the interface to something else, for example, `MyMediaPlayer`, and use it like:

```
MyMediaPlayer P = new MP3();
```

Comment: It may be enough to remove `import android.media.MediaPlayer;` if it's among imports

Comment: @barbsan Yup. If the import is present and is not needed at all, a solution would be to just remove it. I'm not much an android dev, so, I'm not sure in this case if this available by default or just by importing it.